# Tick boxes and Dropdown

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

Have a look at the image below:

[image]

This is "Plain Buger" item - customer can select sauces and extras with it. There are different sizes for Plain Burger.

I need to translate this UI into database design, here what I have came up with:

```
mysql> select * from category;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Burgers |
|  2 | Pizzas  |
+----+---------+
```

-

```
mysql> select * from items;
+----+-------------+--------------+
| id | category_id | name         |
+----+-------------+--------------+
|  1 |           1 | Plain Burger |
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

Plain Burger is belong with "Burgers" category (`category_id = 1`)

-

```
mysql> select * from items_options;
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| id | item_id | name   | price |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | Small  |  3.50 |
|  2 |       1 | Medium |  4.50 |
|  3 |       1 | Large  |  5.50 |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
```

Plain Burger come with different sizes and the price.

-

```
mysql> select * from extras;
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | name        | price |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | ketchup     |  0.00 |
|  2 | Mayo        |  0.00 |
|  3 | Boiled Rice |  0.00 |
|  4 | Chips       |  0.00 |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

-

```
mysql> select * from groups;
+----+--------+--------------------+-----------+
| id | name   | subject            | type      |
+----+--------+--------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Sauces |                    | tickboxes |
|  2 | Extras | Choose your extras | dropdown  |
+----+--------+--------------------+-----------+
```

There is where you can create group of extras/sauces/sides/topping for pizzas.
   As you can see on the UI, Plain Burger come with Sauces and Extras

-

```
mysql> select * from groups_extras;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | group_id | extra_id |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |        1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |        2 |
|  3 |        2 |        3 |
|  4 |        2 |        4 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

After creating the groups, I need to associate the group with the extras. 
Example: Sauces (`group_id = 1`) are related with Ketchup and Mayo

-

```
mysql> select * from groups_extras_options;
+----+------------------+-----------+
| id | items_options_id | groups_id |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 |                1 |         1 |
|  2 |                2 |         1 |
|  3 |                3 |         1 |
|  4 |                1 |         2 |
|  5 |                2 |         2 |
|  6 |                3 |         2 |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

Finally I need to apply group to the options. Example: Small (items_options_id = 1) relate with Sauces group (`group_id = 1`)

I hope I have explained well, is this good database design or what could have been improved?

Let assume the following items:

**Category**: Curries

**Item Name: Balti**

Option name: Chicken 6.00 (With Extras/Groups)

Option name: Lamb 6.50 (With Extras/Groups)

Option name: Prawns 7.50 (With Extras/Groups)

**Item Name: Vindaloo**

Option name: Chicken 8.50 (With Extras/Groups)

Option name: Lamb 6.50 (With Extras/Groups)

Option name: Prawns 7.50

As you can see items come with same options name but the prices can be different.  You notice Balti:Prawns come with extras but Vindaloo:Prawns don't have one.

Sometime I want to apply extras groups to an item which mean it will apply to all related options.

Sometime, I want to apply extras groups to specific options from an item.

How can I normalize my tables above to allow that?

**SQL Dump**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Burgers'),
(2, 'Pizzas');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `extras` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `price` double(6,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


INSERT INTO `extras` (`id`, `name`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 'ketchup', 0.00),
(2, 'Mayo', 0.00),
(3, 'Boiled Rice', 0.00),
(4, 'Chips', 0.00);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `groups` (`id`, `name`, `subject`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 'Sauces', '', 'tickboxes'),
(2, 'Extras', 'Choose your extras', 'dropdown');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups_extras` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extra_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;



INSERT INTO `groups_extras` (`id`, `group_id`, `extra_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 2, 3),
(4, 2, 4);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups_extras_options` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `items_options_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `groups_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;



INSERT INTO `groups_extras_options` (`id`, `items_options_id`, `groups_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 3, 1),
(4, 1, 2),
(5, 2, 2),
(6, 3, 2);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;


INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `category_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Plain Burger');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_options` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


INSERT INTO `items_options` (`id`, `item_id`, `name`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Small', '3.50'),
(2, 1, 'Medium', '4.50'),
(3, 1, 'Large', '5.50');
```

Comment: Still no reply?!

Comment: Not a full answer, but to account for the `Prawns` example above, you could have a boolean field that indicates "DefaultBuildOnly" or something that disallows options with that particular base item.

Comment: There is no need for boolean field. Check `groups_extras_options` result. It apply item to the group's (item to many group's)

Comment: Then why ask about it if you already know how you want to handle it?  I was assuming you had other relationships you needed to keep mapped there that conflicted with removing options from particular items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points that stand out:

**In the table `items_options`**, in your output you have the names like 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large'. If these generic option names are going to be used for different items, as you indicate here:

> As you can see items come with same options name but the prices can be different. You notice Balti:Prawns come with extras but Vindaloo:Prawns don't have one.

Then I would change to have an `options` table, and modify `items_options` to use the new `option_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `options` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_options` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `option_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

This way, if you ever change the name of the option, you only have to do so in one row.

**Create a new table** `items_extras` to handle this case:

> Sometime I want to apply extras groups to an item which mean it will apply to all related options.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_extras` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `extra_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**The table** `groups_extras_options` is misleading, because it does not utilize your `groups_extras.id` column. I would rename the table to `items_options_extras`, so that it would handle this business decision:

> Sometime, I want to apply extras groups to specific options from an item.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_options_extras` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `item_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `extra_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Now, you should be able to get a list of all extras that belong to all options for a selected item, as well as all extras for the specific option that was selected.

You can further group them as you want by utilizing the `groups_extras` table.

**Using foreign keys** would be a good idea, since you are using InnoDB. The idea is to enforce the referential integrity between these tables. As an example, if you add a foreign key on `item_option.item_id` that references `item.id`, you let the database handle situations that you cannot have a particular `item_option` if the `item_id` does not exist in the `item` table. You can read more information on how MySQL handles foreign keys [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

---

*Disclaimer:* This was done quickly, so there might be other things to change. These are the points that stood out the most, though. Also, I changed your id columns to be singular because that is my practice.

Comment: Thanks you very much for detailed response. Just two questions. `items_extras` and `items_options_extras` tables you have provided. I think you meant `extra_id` to be `groups_id`?

Comment: Second question: If multiple items have same options name and if I've rename the option name from the backend (eg: Donner to Donner Special) - I don't want all items that have same Option name to be replaced..

Comment: @user791022 This is what I don't understand. Why would you want 'groups_id' in a table with the name 'extras'. No, I meant 'extras_id'. I am picturing that the individual extras are mapped to items and items_options. But they are ALSO mapped to groups. Two different things.

Comment: `extra_id`'s (ketchup, Mayo, etc)  already mapped into group (see `groups` and `groups_extras`) - so therefore use `groups_id` to apply in `items_options_extras` or `items_options_extras`

Comment: By mapping a 'groups_id' to the items_extras or items_options_extras, that would mean ALL extras in that group are applied to that item or item_option. If that's what you want, ok. My method allows you to have each extra apply to item or item_option, as well as grouped the way you want.

Comment: As for "I don't want all items that have same Option name to be replaced" in this case, you would create a new option name 'Donner Special' and map only the items  you want to change to the new option_id.